# What do I use to replace ToNullSafeString() removed from AutoMapper 3?

Tags: automapper

I have code using AutoMapper 3.2.1.0 that uses the method ToNullSafeString().
I upgraded the NUGet package to 4.1.1.0, and I can no longer find the method in their package.Does anyone know the recommended approach to replacing the function? Is there a new construct that is functionally equivalent? If so, I cannot figure what it is. Nor can I find any mention of why it was removed.

Comment: It was moved to Automapper.Internal as per [this issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/311) - the code in the method is just this, anyway: `return value == null ? null : value.ToString();`

Comment: yes, that was correct a long time ago. But recently, it was removed entirely. Not simply moved to another namespace.

Comment: In any case, I decompiled it like you did and finally just threw the extension method into my project. It was an easy fix. I  was curious what the author was doing as I could not see any meaningful explanation in the source control history as to why it was removed.

Answer (score 3):

This question has actually been answered pretty well in a couple of comments below it. For completeness, here are a couple of actual implementations of solutions.

**Short answer**

Probably both the simplest and the best solution: Replace all instances of `.ToNullSafeString()` with `?.ToString()`. This does the same, but uses functionality built into newer versions of .Net instead of relying on an external extension method.

**Alternative answer**

If you've got a bunch of calls to the `ToNullSafeString()` method from the earlier version Automapper, and for some reason or other you can't or don't want to go through all your code and edit it away right now, you can use this instead.

Add the following class to your project, and make sure it can be reached from any classes that previously called the Automapper-method. Those calls will then automatically point to this instead.

```
public static class NullSafeStringHelper
{
    public static string ToNullSafeString(this object value)
    {
        return value?.ToString();
    }
}
```